# How to deal with SPD problem w.r.t. matrix spectral constrains?

Tags: optimization, normed-spaces, convex-optimization, semidefinite-programming

We have an SPD problem defined as:
$$\begin{aligned}
v^*=\max{} & \operatorname{tr}(V X)\\
\text{s.t. } & \|V\|_2\le1 \\
&V,X\in\mathcal{S}^n
\end{aligned}$$
where $\mathcal{S}^n$ is a space containing all $n\times n$ symmetry matrices. $X$ is given. $\|V\|_2$ is the spectral norm (http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SpectralNorm.html)

How to prove that the maximum  $v^*=\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|$, while $\lambda_i$ is the eigenvalues of $X$.

My Trying:

As hinted by @Brian Borchers, $X$ can be decomposed as $X=PDP^T$ in which $P$ is an orthogonal matrix.

$$tr(VX)=tr(VPDP^T)=tr(P^TVPD)$$

I guess if we can prove $tr(AD)=\sum_{i=1}^n |\lambda_i|$, the problem will be solved. But how to prove this? and how to connect this with $tr(P^TVPD)$?

Comment: @copper.hat X is given.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What would happen if $X$ was a diagonal matrix?  Have you tried to diagonalize $X$?   Have you taken advantage of the fact that the spectral norm of $V$ is orthogonally invariant?

Comment: @BrianBorchers I have some tryings added, but there are still some gap bwtween the result.

Comment: Horrible notation. Conventionally, the first letters of the alphabet denote what is given, whereas the last letters denote what is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a rather tedious answer:

It is clear that we can take $X$ to be diagonal with entries $\lambda_k$. By choosing $V$ to be diagonal with entries $\operatorname{sgn} \lambda_k$ we get $v^* \ge \sum_k |\lambda_k|$.

To establish an upper bound, note that we can take $V$ to have the form
$U\Sigma U^T$ where $U$ is orthogonal and $\Sigma$ is diagonal with diagonal entries $|\sigma_k| \le 1$. We can write
$V= \sum_i \sigma_i u_i u_i^T$
to get
$\operatorname{tr} (XV) = \sum_i \sigma_i \operatorname{tr} (Xu_i u_i^T) = \sum_i \sigma_i u_i^T X u_i = \sum_i \sigma_i \sum_k \lambda_k [u_i]_k^2 = \sum_k \lambda_k \sum_i \sigma_i [u_i]_k^2 $,
and so
$\operatorname{tr} (XV) \le \sum_k |\lambda_k| \sum_i |\sigma_i| [u_i]_k^2 \le \sum_k |\lambda_k|$.

Hence we have the desired result.